Twilio whatsapp Otp failing even after getting template approv



I am using flutter to send this message.  The template is approved and still i am getting error.
final TwilioFlutter twilioFlutter = TwilioFlutter(
    accountSid:
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', // replace with Account SID
    authToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // replace with Auth Token
    twilioNumber:
        '+xxxxxxxxxxx', // replace with Twilio Number(With country code)
  );

Future<void> sendOtp(String otp, String phoneNumber) async {
  String messageBody = "Hi, Enter 123456 to continue";
  try {
    await twilioFlutter.sendWhatsApp(
      toNumber: '+91$phoneNumber',
      messageBody: messageBody,
    );
    print('OTP sent successfully');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Failed to send OTP: $e');
  }
}

I tried encoding the data before sending but to no avail

The problem was with whatsapp custom template and twilio_flutter package. You can post a request via curl from your code like:
  Future<void> sendOtp(String otp, String phoneNumber) async {
    final String accountSid =
        'xxx'; // replace with Account SID
    final String authToken =
        'xxx'; // replace with Auth Token
    final String twilioNumber =
        '+xxx'; // replace with Twilio Number(With country code)
    final String messagingServiceSid = 'xxx';
    final String contentSid ="xxx";

    Map<String, String> contentVariables = {
        "1":otp
      };

  // Encode contentVariables to JSON string

  // Print or use encodedContentVariables as needed
    final url =
        'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${accountSid}/Messages.json';

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Authorization':
            'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('${accountSid}:${authToken}')),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: {
        'From':'whatsapp:$twilioNumber',
        'To':'whatsapp:+91$phoneNumber',
        'MessagingServiceSid':messagingServiceSid,
        'ContentSid': contentSid,
        'ContentVariables': contentVariables,
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      print('OTP sent successfully');
    } else {
      print('Failed to send OTP: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response: ${response.body}');
    }
  }

